# add text along arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations

I created the following image with MS Visio: [image]

### MWE

Now I want to create it with Tikz.
Therefor I already got an MWE to this:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{g1}{RGB}{235,240,245}
\definecolor{g2}{RGB}{223,230,237}
\definecolor{g3}{RGB}{205,217,225}
\definecolor{g4}{RGB}{190,205,215}
\definecolor{g5}{RGB}{173,190,203}
\definecolor{g6}{RGB}{155,175,190}
\definecolor{g7}{RGB}{135,155,170}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (7,1.75);
    \foreach \n [count=\i] in {28,24,...,4}{
        \fill[g\i, draw=black] (28em,0) circle (\n em);
    }
    \draw[black, line width=0.75pt] (0,0) -- (7,0) -- (7,1.75) -- (0.215,1.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Result

whicht produces:
[image]
(note: this has an additional circle, that is intended)

### Question

How can I reproduce the text as in the first image?

And besides the text: Is my MWE optimal? (In the means of sizing (using just 7 cm width which will lead to really big text) and coding of repeated functions.)

Comment: You can use a foreach loop for the circles

Comment: If there's an extra circle, which one should be the empty circle: smallest or the biggest?

Comment: @Alenanno I don't understand what you mean. I added an extra circle because I had an additional layer in my work case. If you mean the arc of the text, than there should be an arc between every two where the text should align so that is has a mean bending

Comment: I meant that there are 6 "texts", but 7 circles in your own solution, where you say you added an extra one. So, which circle should be empty, as in without text?

Comment: Ah ok. The fifth from the left should be empty ;) But for your example you can type some blindtext.

Comment: See decorations by path on page 351 of the PGF manual.

Comment: As an MWE, it would be much improved if you provided the texts you want written along the paths.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possible solution:

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, intersections}

\definecolor{g8}{RGB}{255,255,255} %to trick foreach
\definecolor{g1}{RGB}{235,240,245}
\definecolor{g2}{RGB}{223,230,237}
\definecolor{g3}{RGB}{205,217,225}
\definecolor{g4}{RGB}{190,205,215}
\definecolor{g5}{RGB}{173,190,203}
\definecolor{g6}{RGB}{155,175,190}
\definecolor{g7}{RGB}{135,155,170}

\tikzset{
    curvetext/.style n args={4}{postaction={decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\sffamily#2|#3},
            text align={center, left indent=1mm, #4},
            raise=#1,
            reverse path,
            %text effects/.cd,
            every character/.style={draw},
            %text width=2cm,
            }}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-.1,0) rectangle (28em,2);
\foreach \angle/\texta/\textb [count=\j, evaluate=\j as \x using int(32-4*\j)] in {%
    0/,
    -6/Zaun mit Tor/,
    -7/Uberwachungs-/kameras,
    -9/verschlossene/Schaltwarte,
    -11/pw-geschutzte/Bedienung,
    -25/,
    -32/verschlossene/Schaltschranke,
    20/2-Augen-/prinzip
}{%
    \ifnum\j=8
    \path[
         curvetext={-3mm}{\scriptsize\phantom{,}}{\texta}{},
         curvetext={-6mm}{\scriptsize\phantom{,}}{\textb}{},
         ]
    (28em,4em) arc (90:180:4em);
    \else
    \begin{scope}[shift={(28em,0)}]
    \draw[
        fill=g\j, rotate=\angle,
        curvetext={7mm}{\scriptsize}{\texta}{},
        curvetext={4mm}{\scriptsize}{\textb}{}
        ] 
    (0,0) circle (\x em);
    \end{scope}
    \fi
}%
\path[name path=circ] (28em,0) circle (28em);
\path[name path=horiz] (-.1,2) --++ (5,0);
\path[name intersections={of=circ and horiz,by=E}];
\draw (E) -| (28em,0) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you make the text centered in each area? And please without serifes. And the text in the smallest circle looks a bit stretched, could you resize it?

Comment: @Phil The serifs can be removed by adding `\sffamily` to the second argument of `curvetext`. The other two requests are much harder to implement. Try commenting out the clip, then change the `text align` to `center`, the text will not stay in that position. All of this was manually done and it's not easy to fine tune the text's position.

Comment: @Phil Maybe I found a way. Please, stand by. :P

Comment: Thanks for trying so hard ;) Isn't there a possibility to calculate the length of the path for the text using the readius of the bow and the heigth of the clipping? And then just centering the text ;)

Comment: @Phil Maybe. But that would require a slightly different solution. I'm using the circles as paths, but for your solution, I'd have to make new paths. :P

Comment: @Phil See new edit.

Comment: OK thats a way better than before. I would like to leave this question open some time to maybe see defferent solutions. I'll also update my Question with a solution I got while testing parallel to this.

Comment: @Phil What do you mean by `bow`?

Comment: It should mean arc. Sorry I used the wrong word